# Advice on setting up a cross-platform website scraping project

Tags: python, ide, cross-platform, pyqt, scrapy

Looking for advice on selecting a language and IDE for a scraping application. Here are my requirements:

1. Need to use a language that is good for cross-platform (Win/OSX)
2. Need to use IDE that has good source control for multiple programmers
3. Would like to use a robust library for scraping
4. Would like to make GUI that looks native for each platform

After my initial research this is what I have so far:

1. Python
2. pyQT for GUI
3. Not sure which IDE to use that is good with source control management (Eclipse?)
4. Scrapy.org for scraping
5. Possibly Selenium WebDriver

I am not sure if Scrapy will meet my needs because I need to be able to submit forms on websites that may utilize javascript...so I think Selenium may be able to handle that.

I would prefer not to use Objective C, or C++. I'm leaning towards Python because it seems nice for it's rapid development.

So the question is, am I on the right track or am I just completely missing a totally different and better path to take that will be simpler or more suited to scraping and submitting forms on websites?

Comment: Just a note: you can submit forms using ``scrapy`` check http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest

Comment: YOu have pretty much answered your own question. Please note that SCM and a IDE should not entirely be tied together, but rather up to the developer preference. Final part you also answered for interacting with the javascript web forms.

Comment: Mouad: I saw that, however I am under the impression that it will not be able to submit if the form submission utilizes javascript vs. a standard html form.

Comment: Sean: essentially you are saying I am on the right track. Which makes me feel more confident if I go down this route.